# Loop through particular type of controls on a form (e.g. all text boxes)

Tags: ms-access, vba

How would I loop through all text boxes on form (ignoring any other type of control that might be on the form).

For example, I'd quite like to do some validation that gives a list of the text boxes that are empty on a form.

This sort of gives me what I'm after:

```vb
Public Sub emptyFields()

    Dim txt As Control
    Dim msgText As String

    msgText = ""

    For Each txt In Me.Controls

        If _
            IsNull(txt) _
        Then

            msgText = msgText & vbCrLf & txt.Tag

        End If

    Next txt

    MsgBox "Please complete the following:" & vbCrLf & msgText    
End Sub
```

However, I can tell this is looping through **all** of the other controls on the form as these are getting a blank line in the `MsgBox` text.

I'd also prefer to use the `.Caption` property of the text boxes, which doesn't seem to be available in the above method (probably because not all controls have captions), hence why I've used the `.Tag` property instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the ControlType.

```
Sub AllText()
Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then
        Debug.Print "textbox"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Only Labels have a Caption property, however, Item 0 of the control's Controls Collection is the label, so:

```
 Debug.Print ctl.Controls.Item(0).Caption
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! And yes, no `.Caption` property for textboxes... I must have been confusing that with command button properties.